# If your UX Design team is to divide into 4 different levels from Beginner to Expert, what could be the acceptance criteria?

Tags: ux-designer, team

I want to divide my UX Design team into 4 different levels from beginner level to expert level.
What could be their acceptance criteria based on their skills related to (core skills, communication skills, management skills, etc)

Comment: This will depend on your company and will vary from company to company, and UX team to UX team, so you might not be able to get an answer you are looking for to this question. Also, there are different specializations within UX, e.g. Usability Researcher, Usability Tester, Information Architect, Interaction Designer, Visual Designer, UI Developer.

Comment: @Splatz Its specially for UI/UX based startup company.

Comment: Who is going to lead the UI/UX people? Is it someone who has had a career as a UX person?

Comment: Any how many UI and UX people will be in the team?

Comment: Yes, Team lead will be the person who has had a career as UX person for about 6yrs. 
There will about 10 -12 UI/UX person in total.

Comment: That is a large team, so I assume some will be UI developers who code the solution (HTML, CSS and JS) and others with be UX people who may (or may not) specialise in the various sub-roles within UX. If so then the experience levels will vary from discipline to discipline. Time in a role is another measure.

Comment: Yes, it's kind of large UI/UX team. Can we generalize the measurement and divide them in different levels?

Comment: http://adaptivepath.org/ideas/a-model-for-ux-career-growth/

Comment: Not really. A UI Developer is very different to a UX Designer. they will have very different education and career paths. What is defined as Beginner for a UI Developer will be different to UX Researcher. It will be difficult to generalise, which is why I mentioned Time, e.g. A Beginner will have <1 year experience, while an Expert will have 10+ years experience. So some metrics can be generalise while others will be specific to the specialization.

Comment: based on your answers I am assuming this is to help with recruitment, rather than shaping a career plan. If you are using a recruitment agency they can also help you shape this. The link provided by @midas is very good for the UX side, but will not really help with the UI developer role.

Comment: It's not for an recruitment agency. Could you help to create these levels separately for UI design team and UX design team?